# How can I adjust the offset of two divs?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

[image: layout of left]

[image: layout of left_feature]

[image]

Here is the structure of my web page. I created three divs under content, left, centre and right. Centre and right both have offset 641, same as content class.
However, offset of left_feature is different from others, leading to elements of left not aligning with other elements. I tried to set the padding, border and margin-top but these did not change. I tried inspection of element and successfully forced element of left to move to correct position once by setting padding and margin but never succeeded again. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I hope I could because the web page contains some confidential information.

Comment: You need to create a demo, otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Comment: https://na.cx/i/XUMh9r.png that is the situation. If that's not enough, I may have to leave the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That offset is basically the x,y  position that the browser has calculated for the element based on it's position css attribute.

if you are using `display: inline-block;` just specify vertical alignment of the elements like,

```
vertical-align: middle | top | bottom
```

or

use `position: absolute;` for the divs

or

play with `negative margin` to adjust the same.